# How do I feed (Postgresql) data into GTK entry fields?

Tags: python, postgresql, gtk3

Trying to set up a Python 3 program to display and edit data from a Postgresql database. The attached code is a simplified "hard coded" example of what I am trying (actually using an equivalent Gtk.Builder construction.)
Without the "set_text" instruction, the Vcard window is displayed exactly how I want it.

Here is the trace-back:

```
$ python3 Q1.py
Database connection closed.
Record(vindex=5, prefix='Mrs D ', firstname='Nona', addnlnames=None, surname='***', suffix=None, nickname=None, kind='private', bday=None, anniversary=None, gender=None, workpobox=None, workaddr2=None, workaddr=None, workcity=None, workstate=None, workpostcode=None, workcountry=None, homepobox=None, homeaddr2=None, homeaddr='********', homecity='****', homestate=None, homepostcode='BT** ***', homecountry='N Ireland', worktel=None, hometel='02870 ******', faxtel=None, pagertel=None, mobiletel='07931 ******', email1=None, email2=None, title=None, workrole=None, workdept=None, workorg=None, rev=None, notes=None, webpage=None, orgwebpage=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q1.py", line 92, in <module>
    y = displaydata(x)
  File "Q1.py", line 81, in displaydata
    Vcard.prefixentry.set_text(xstr(c['prefix']))
AttributeError: type object 'Vcard' has no attribute 'prefixentry'
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from collections import deque
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
from outputvcard import *
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

c = {}
version = "2.1"
buffer = deque([])
lastname = "Bell"

def readacard( lastname, cc ):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='contacts' user='postgres'")
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
    cur.execute("SELECT * from vcardata where surname = %s", [lastname])
    cc = cur.fetchone()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    print('Database connection closed.')
    return cc;

class Vcardclass(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Vcard editor", application=app)
        self.set_title("Vcard editor")
        self.set_default_size(300, 600)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(self.vbox)
        self.swin = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(expand=True)
        self.swin.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS, Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS)
        self.swin.set_vadjustment
        self.vbox.add(self.swin)
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.swin.add(self.grid)

        self.prefixlabel = Gtk.Label("Prefix")
        self.prefixentry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.grid.attach(self.prefixlabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid.attach(self.prefixentry, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.prefixentry.set_text(xstr(c['prefix']))

        self.firstnamelabel = Gtk.Label("First name")
        self.firstnameentry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.grid.attach_next_to(self.firstnamelabel, self.prefixlabel, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1,1)
        self.grid.attach_next_to(self.firstnameentry, self.prefixentry, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1,1)
"""
lots more like that
"""


class Vcard(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        window = Vcardclass(self)
        window.show_all()

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

app = Vcard()

def xstr(s):
    if s is None:
        return ''
    else:
        return s

def displaydata(c):
    print (c)
    Vcard.prefixentry.set_text(xstr(c['prefix']))
    Vcard.firstnameentry.set_text(xstr(c['firstname']))
"""
lots more like that
"""




x = readacard(lastname, c)
#print (x)
y = displaydata(x)
x = outcard(version, c, buffer)
i = len(buffer)
outfile = 'out.vcf'
f = open(outfile, 'w')
while i > 0:
    f.write(buffer.popleft() + "\n")
    i = i - 1
    f.close

exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Many thanks for your input
Graeme

Comment: Not to offend you, but your code is poorly designed. Would you like a beginners version of Gtk, Python, and Postgresql? Or are you intentionally using advanced Python/Gtk methods ?

Comment: As a beginner to Python, though not without experience in other computer languages, I try to understand tutorials found at various websites and build an application incrementally. . At the moment I'm not worried about exception handling, but I welcome comments on improving the design. In particular, I need to understand why an instance of Vcardclass is not recognised, and how to use set_text and get_text to display and modify data. I am using Gtk.Builder because of its WYSIWYG capability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic app to get you started.

Python:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk
import os, sys, psycopg2

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('app.ui')
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='contacts' user='postgres'")
            self.cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
        except Exception, e:
            print e

        window = self.builder.get_object('window')
        window.show_all()

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def button_clicked (self, button):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * from vcardata where surname = %s", [lastname])
        cc = self.cur.fetchone()[0]
        self.builder.get_object('entry1').set_text(str(cc))

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Glade file with name `app.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.0"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">window</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">400</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Click here to run SQL command</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Feel free to ask for explanation on anything you don't understand

Comment: Many thanks for my "starter for 10". I've worked it to display my basic GUI window, but I've too much on for the moment to develop it further. I'll gladly take up your offer if I can't proceed.

Comment: This code was copy and paste from [PyGtk Posting](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygtk-posting/). It is a small business accounting software I develop for my own use in my spare time :) You may find some more useful info in that project.

Comment: Reference PyGtk Posting: Please advise how to modify "db_settings"; I can't find a suitable function.

Comment: Please ignore - I realise what's happening.